# OkHttp - сайт требует включенный cookie

Tags: java, android, cookie, okhttp

**Цель:** личное приложение для получения остатка трафика через личный кабинет МегаФона посредством парсинга.

**Проблема:** при запросе на получение исходника страницы `https://lk.megafon.ru/login/` (для дальнейшего парсинга скрытых инпутов формы входа) приходит страница с ошибкой

> Для корректной работы личного кабинета включите в вашем браузере работу с cookie-файлами

Использую `OkHttp`. Вот мой класс для работы с cookie:

```
public class CookieProvider {

    public static HashMap<String, List<Cookie>> cookieStore = new HashMap<>();

    public static OkHttpClient get() {
        CookieJar cookieJarGetter = new CookieJar() {
            @Override
            public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {

            }
            @Override
            public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
                return cookieStore.get(url.host());
            }
        };

        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().
            cookieJar(cookieJarGetter).
            build();
    }
    public static OkHttpClient save() {
        CookieJar cookieJarSaver = new CookieJar() {
            @Override
            public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
                cookieStore.clear();
                cookieStore.put(url.host(), cookies);
            }
            @Override
            public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
                return new ArrayList<Cookie>();
            }
        };
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().
            cookieJar(cookieJarSaver).
            build();
    }
}
```

Сам запрос:

```
AndroidNetworking.get("https://lk.megafon.ru/login").
        setOkHttpClient(CookieProvider.save()).
        build().
        getAsString(new StringRequestListener(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String login) {
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(login);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, doc.toString(), 1).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ANError error) {
                showError();
            }
        });
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысла в этом провайдере 0, так как вы не используете сохранённые cookie. Попробуйте объединить эти методы примерно в следующее:

```
public class CookieStore implements CookieJar {

    private final HashMap<String, List<Cookie>> mCookieStore = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
        mCookieStore.put(url.host(), cookies);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
        return mCookieStore.get(url.host());
    }

    public void clear() {
        mCookieStore.clear();
    }
}
```

Сам запрос:

```
AndroidNetworking.get("https://lk.megafon.ru/login")
    .setOkHttpClient(new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cookieJar(new CookieStore())
        .build())
    .build()
    .getAsString(new StringRequestListener(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String login) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(login);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, doc.toString(), 1).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError error) {
            showError();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Далее куки же надо передавать. Я буду их использовать

Comment: @Flippy здесь это реализовано

Comment: А для каждого запроса получается будет создаваться экземпляр этого класса? И куки будут недоступны в дальнейшем?

Comment: Вызывается `onError`